# Add 'this is my first post' (and several other phrases) to the question content filter

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It's well-known on Stack Overflow (and perhaps all of Stack Exchange) that the first line of every question/answer is checked using regular expression against a list of unallowed words & phrases.

Simple words such as 'Hello' and 'Hi' are disallowed, but lately I've noticed a few (new) questions using the phrase `this is my first post`, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752314/c-file-editing-without-deleting-other-information).

[image]

Such edits are trivial and I'd personally prefer *not* to have to make such small changes such as this in the first place.

I've also noticed `I apologize`, `apologies`, , and `sorry if i'm not posting to the right section` being pretty popular mainly with new users also.

Please could the following phrases be added to the 'first sentence content filter' (feel free to add to this list if you have any suggestions):

- this is my first post
- i am a student
- I apologize
- apologies
- I am a beginner
- I am a [place programming language here] noob (see this question: [Drools optaplanner rule not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714618/noob-drools-optaplanner-rule-help-appreciated))
- sorry if i'm not posting [to whatever]
- i'm a newbie here
- i am new to [whatever programming language]
- i searched on the web but [statement here]
- i want to know how

There are [many `I am a noob`](https://www.google.gg/?gws_rd=ssl#q='I%20am%20a%20noob'%20site%3Astackoverflow.com) questions:

[image]

If not, is there a specific reason why?

Comment: other frequent noisy phrases are "newbie here", "I am new to"

Comment: @gnat Added them to the list :-).

Comment: Some have argued that "I'm new" remarks have some redeeming value in that they allow the answerers to tune the wording of their answers such that they are comprehensible to a beginner in the field. I personally disagree; this information is implicit in the question being ask. E.g. don't need "I'm noob" when the question is "how do I assign a value to a variable?"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Agreed, I personally judge a users' expertise on the code that they provide & the way it is written. I've also seen that 'i'm a noob' and 'im new' questions always seem to go downhill.

Comment: Then there's the ever-popular 'I searched on the web but didn't find anything', AKA 'do my homework research for me'.

Comment: @MartinJames Added to the list.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm not sure I agree on that one - we ask people to indicate what they've tried and what they've found. It's perfectly valid to have a question where the OP is unable to find information online and they should definitely call that out (although we should encourage them to be specific about where they look).

Comment: @thegrinner While I agree with you, users should *not* be starting with 'i searched for' in their question.

Comment: @thegrinner: "I searched and didn't find anything" is often a lie.  "I searched for 'frobbing gadgets in python' but the first two pages of results are all about frobbing widgets instead" is much more likely to be from actual experience (and it's verifiable modulo Google result personalization).

Comment: Wow, just found a really good examplequestion, hits the suggestions three times ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761518/simple-java-looping-over-a-txt-file-of-numbers-counting-the-numbers-between-a

Comment: @thegrinner not once have I seen someone claim that they had searched to no avail and that it was true. not once. most of the time, the first result of googling their exact question title is exactly their answer

Comment: While most of these are obvious, sometimes they're just the result of not being able to formulate a question clearly. For example, "i want to know how" could be written by anybody. I've seen "Thanks in advice", "any suggestions are welcome", etc. by people who aren't new users as well. "Please help" and "give me suggestions" however seem to be more newbie-ish. "What am I doing wrong", "what's wrong with my code"...

Comment: I would like to never see the phrase "please help" again.  Please help me.

Comment: Also phrases like "Thanks in advance" or similar should be blocked

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: Actually, google is quite fast in indexing new questions, so the first hit is likely to be the noobs question, you must look at the second one ;-)

Comment: "I'd personally prefer not to have to make such small changes such as this in the first place."  Then why do you???

Comment: @HotLicks Removing noise makes the site more useful for future readers.

Comment: Removing noise makes more noise.

Comment: Not sure, what is the reason to make it such a `fuss`? Let it be there. It's not rude/offensive. So what gives.

Comment: What @FélixGagnon-Grenier said. Some people figured out that if they don't make any attempt at finding an answer, folks here don't respond kindly to their question, and started guessing that "i searched but didn't find anything" is the magic phrase that should be added to a poor question to make it a good one, regardless of whether any searching has actually taken place. (Of course, that does not work. What it tells me is that they're liars and the rest of the information in the question shouldn't be trusted either.)

Comment: I wonder if we'll get an answer from one of the moderators, or even senior staff. I believe that only the senior moderators/staff can change this..

Comment: Before it gets deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26782349/1

Comment: @KevinPanko No need to spam that question, I have already dealt with it and edited the fluff out.

Comment: and "thanks in advanced" please please please!

Comment: @Rahul: I wonder.. why did you use code formatting for the word "fuss"? Just curious.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, just to highlight it and nothing more than that. Well I would agree that, I don't know most of the editing feature provide in SO. Probably I should be using some other formatting.

Comment: @Rahul: Okay well for highlighting we have **bold** and *italic*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was going to post something similar to the original Meta question, but having found this, I'll add an answer instead in support of it. I'd quite like to see some kind of filtering for "noise phrases" anywhere in a question, either in the title, first sentence, or indeed anywhere in the body. I am a frequent editor and I'd like to see a drop in the most common noise we get every day.

Such filtering could be optional to start with, and maybe it would stay that way, if turning it on permanently might catch too many false positives (e.g. noise phrases legitimately appearing in code rather than in paragraph text).

Aside from their noise value, there are two particular phrases at the moment that I think demonstrate new users could do with some automated guidance for their posts:

- "Please help [me]" (287K questions). Often accompanied by a sad face emoticon, this sort of begging and pleading actually turns potential answerers off, with the poor OP actually thinking it helps. It is sometimes used in lieu of supplying sufficient detail.
- "Sorry for my [bad] English" (~14K questions). Whilst I still regard this as noise that needs trimming out, I think if we can encourage readers whose first language is not English that they do not need to apologise for this, they might feel a bit more welcome. (True, questions need to be understandable, but apologies don't improve the writing of the question itself, and just give editors more to do).

Since we have content filters for things already (e.g. "problem" in titles) I guess this suggestion should not be too hard to add?

Comment: Re false positives, maybe just send the question into triage or directly into H&I and let a human remove the noise?  Especially "Sorry for my English", which may indicate a question that could use help and improvement by a native writer.

Comment: @Jeffrey, thanks. I have noticed a few occasions where English has been apologised for, but the question is mostly fine (perhaps with minor grammar issues that are not too important). I am not opposed to sending questions to triage/H&I (perhaps if they have other LQ indicators too), but I wonder if we can encourage posters to remove the worst noise themselves?

Answer (score -4):

I respectfully 'somewhat disagree.'  Yes, a lot of noise is a bad thing, but some of it is a warning.  Of course it has no place in the subject line, but it should not be forcefully removed from the question itself.

Perhaps a good way to solve the problem of excess noise would be to introduce a blue (or some other color) squiggly underline that marks LQ-indicator phrases.  And not just phrases, but also missing capitals (i->I, jquery->jQuery, etc.)  But again, these should be suggestions, not filters.  Because most people use i for their loops and sometimes you're using all lower case because it's a url.

My main disagreement is that things like "I searched on the web but [statement here]" should be obvious to everyone, but aren't to some people on both sides of the noob/mod divide.  When someone asks a noob question, this statement is like marking that checkbox "Yes, I've looked!" stating that they have tried to find it and couldn't, and maybe the answerer can direct them in how to find it.  I've seen countless questions that I myself could not find the answers to on any other site, be it w3schools.com, api.jquery.com or the 19+ JavaScript Shortcuts page, and I could only find any reference here on this site, but the question was closed for the answer being supposedly well-documented, and I had to look at another similar question that managed to get answered *before* it was closed.  Yes, some noobs still say that even when it's not true.  But some mods assume it's never true, and close down a question that people have legitimately tried to find the answer to.  Instead of banning the phrase, encourage people to say where they've looked.

The four times I've tried to write a question here, I searched and looked at at least 3 different sites and 3 SO questions that have a similar title and no relation whatsoever, and I start to write a long question and have found the answer by looking at the most obscure related-questions near the bottom of the related-questions sidebar.  But until I get about 3/4 of the way through a post, nothing relevant shows up.  And some people, for the sake of not having questions as long as my posts, simply write "I've looked everywhere I can think of" instead of writing each place they've looked.

But some noise is viewed as a positive thing.  It is conversational and makes more sense to our brains because it is someone asking for help, not a teacher asking a question on a test.  I agree that there's a fine line between too much and not enough.  But writing "Thanks in Advance!" on a question is like writing "Sincerely," on a letter.  Adding "I'm new to javascript" to "How do you turn a string into an array?" is the difference between the following answers:

- Just use `json.parse(string)`
- `string.split(',')` divides a string at each comma it comes across and puts each piece into an array, in order.  At the end, there will be no commas in any of the substrings stored in the array.  The argument determines the delimiter, or what this method uses to split up the string.

Comment: " this statement is like marking that checkbox "Yes, I've looked!" " That's where you are wrong. It actually only means "I'm pretending I'm going through the motions so stop bugging me and give me my answer already, damnit!" Or maybe the checkbox thingy is actually more apt than I want to give credit for, as paper is patient.

Comment: "But some noise is viewed as a positive thing" Yes, by those who don't know what SO is for, and thus how it works, it's sometimes seen that way. SO is not about conversations, discussions, tutoring or the like though, but building a lasting collection of Q&A for specific programming problems. Look more to scientific publications or wikipedia articles for the proper style. Some link for you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: The general layout of a question should be like a book; a beginning (defining *what* you're trying to do), middle (defining the *problem*, and stating what you've already tried), and an end (again, stating what you've tried).

Answer (score -23):

Why?  A newbie will presumably only use the "first post" tag at worst 2-3 times, and other phrases the first ten or so.  Generally there will be other much worse wording problems with the post that will make it hard to read & understand, so focusing on this stuff is a distraction.

And there's no need to edit them out -- it serves no real purpose to do so, other than to create more churn.  (Though I suppose it does give the OCD sorts among us something to do.)

Comment: Did I mention 'newbies'? I find that for a question to *be a question*, it must flow nicely; words at the beginning of the question such as 'this is my first post' makes for 'horrible' reading, and there's no flow to the question.

Comment: It would be an interesting study.

Comment: @cybermonkey - So you think that lots of regulars type "this is my first post"???  (And, if so, you think that blocking that phrase will prevent them from simply switching to a different one?)

Comment: @cybermonkey - There is absolutely no need for you to go around editing out such phrases.

Comment: @HotLicks Did you actually *read the question*? It suggests *many* other forms that need to be dealt with also. I also mentioned editing in the beginning, ***this question talks about the question word filter, which is an entirely different scenario altogether.***

Comment: @cybermonkey - Yes, and most of them are newbie stuff, and pretty trivial.  No real purpose is served by trying to eliminate them, either before or after the fact.

Comment: @HotLicks Most, if not all, of those phrases are generally considered fluff, which a lot of users that edit a question will remove. It's unnecessary noise.

Comment: @HotLicks I find some regular users also do it; a couple of hours ago I saw a question in the review queue that had this, and was from a 1 rep user, *however the question had been edited by another user but still had the junk in it*. Obviously I failed the question and it got deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @Kendra - If I need to edit a question to make it more understandable I will remove some of the "fluff" (if present).  But I see no point in editing out such stuff just to do it.  **What purpose is served??**

Comment: @HotLicks The purpose served is clearing up the clutter of the question to get more straight to the point. If I'm coming from Google looking for the solution to my question, what do I care if you're brand new to programming, or a "noob" with Java? I don't, and the information is irrelevant to the problem at hand and should be removed. On top of that, we are trying to build a high-quality knowledge base. Fluff like that is _not_ high-quality. It's not needed at all.

Comment: @Kendra has nailed it on the spot; we don't care whether they're a student, brand new to programming, a 'noob', or if they're a newbie- ***we're here to give help to those who seek it, not learn about their life-stories***.

Comment: Editing out fluff is not hard, and I've never seen anyone complain when I do it. The issue is that once you edit out the fluff, it is hard to leave the question in an answerable state. I would follow [George Stocker's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker) example as I've seen him turn a crap question into a good one, but it requires practice.

Comment: @remyabel Very true, yesterday I was editing a question that had loads of fluff and was badly in need of editing- thing is, once I'd stripped the fluff out the question was in an unanswerable state.

Comment: @Kendra - If much of this sort of stuff is present the odds are excellent that the "intellectual content" of the question is negligible anyway.  The myth that SO is building up some fantastic collection of hyper-intellectual literature is just that -- a myth.

Comment: @HotLicks The idea is for the questions to become useful later, so that when you have a problem, say "not enough foo to start the wozzulator" you can just plug that into Google, find the [so] question saying "Why do I not have enough foo?" and the answer will be right underneath.  If the user posted that as their first question, nobody needs to know that, and it's just extra noise in the way of you getting to your answer.

Comment: @KevinPanko - The odds of the question becoming useful later are vanishingly small.

Comment: @HotLicks - I've always thought that saying "the odds of this becoming useful later is really small" is a bit silly. My answer is: "so what?" I've had an answer to a bad question downvoted because "this question or answer will never be useful" and a few months later it has 5 upvotes... it must have been useful to someone. As you know, SO is consistently at the top of search results... so why not go the extra mile?

Comment: So why allow downvotes at all, then?  (Especially since downvoting is often unrelated to the merits of the question.)

Comment: @HotLicks Because voting signals to the user what the best answer likely is.