# Should I edit posts to capitalize the word "i" if there is any lowercase?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I tend to edit posts when I encounter any spelling error and also capitalize "i"s if they are unintentionally left in lowercase. Today, I did edit and only capitalized "i"s without editing other content (see [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13558256)). However, I got 2 rejections from reviews and their comment was:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I partially agree with the statement. Having said that the edit got 3 approve, so should posts be edited to capitalize "i"s?

Comment: This has already been discussed many times.

Comment: I have read that

Comment: There's even more to fix. If you edit that pedantically, fix everything please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry it was too late when I see

Comment: If you have read the duplicate then what was unclear about the answers provided there? Because then we can update the posts there.

Comment: @rene What is unclear to me is that why my edit got rejected if it can be  considered “Too minor” edit. Should I not capitalize "i"s?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov You actually should, but as I mentioned above ...

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov you should fix those for posts that need an edit. If the one and only thing to fix is the *i*, I would spend my time and that of the reviewers on posts that really need your edit capabilities. I don't think that was the only post today that badly needed an edit ....

Comment: @rene Your answer satisfied me. I totally agree. If you can, change it to an answer.

Comment: A quick question, why this question marked as "exact duplicate" instead of something like "possible duplicate"

Comment: Because I dupe hammered it. When only one user close votes it is a *possible dupe*, once it is really closed it is an exact dupe. Normally that takes 5 close voters (users with >3K rep) but I happen to have a gold tag dupe hammer for the discussion tag here on meta, so my duplicate close vote is binding.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov no problem, enjoy your editing and improving of posts. That is appreciated.

Comment: Yes. And vote it down + flag VLQ, while you leave a link [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370).

Comment: Whereas the question actually has been answered on that page, the topic of should one capitalize I is actually rather unique. There are MANY people that make an active and contentious choice not to capitalize the letter "I" and to have others come around and say "that is not your choice to make" in a way does take away from the intent of the author when they choose not to capitalize "I". Its not always an issue of bad grammar as can be seen on http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7986/why-should-the-first-person-pronoun-i-always-be-capitalized

Comment: @peterh not that much aggressive :)

Comment: @Bruce If a native English speaker decides so on his best will, it is to me ok. But if you look through, such a high level of self-confidence is very rare. Typically undereducated, lazy and arrogant jerks use "i", thinking they are above any rule. And they tipically interpret the fixes as an attack. Through purging this behavior, I actually target their mentality.

Comment: @peterh I agree with you, but the question seemed to imply that the ONLY changes were capitalization of "I" and at that point, I say you may well be stepping on toes.

Comment: @Bruce: I have often said it is a misuse of the "author's intent" guideline to assert posters may violate well-understood rules of case, spelling, grammar etc deliberately for stylistic reasons. Whilst we try to be forgiving of people who do not know the rules of English, I tend to come down quite hard on people who know their writing style is distracting but choose to do it anyway. [More on this theme here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293779/472495).

Comment: @halfer The problem is, there are not rules to English. That is a vast misconception of the English language. English is a living and breathing language and it has not rules, only guidelines and those guidelines are made up of popular consensus. This is why for example, the word aint' over the past 50 years has gone from being improper slang English, to a word defined in the dictionary as a contraction for am not, or why the word internet just in the last 3 months has changed from a proper noun needing capitalization to a noun which does not. The "rules" are only rules so long as people follow

Comment: @Bruce: if there were no rules to English we would not have dictionaries (and style guides). I take your point that rules/guidelines change, but only to a limited degree: rules change by consensus and rules change slowly. I will be editing out _ain't_ as well - it will probably be listed as _inf._ in the dictionary, and I will firmly discourage it alongside txtspk and begging.

Comment: Agree on 'internet' though - I used to capitalise that, but it began to feel stuffy and formal to do so, and I stopped. I didn't know that the lower-case variant had been accepted as correct - interesting!

Comment: @Bruce Well, that I agree - although in most cases there are other mayor spelling problems as well, rooting clearly in lazyness and not in lack of English.