# How to react to reply "I don't care" to advice not to post a comment as an 'answer'?

Tags: discussion, comments

I came across [this "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270578/6614295) in the review queue. As it is only a comment to the question not an answer, I reviewed it accordingly, thus adding an auto comment, that the corresponding user should not post comments as answers. He replied that he cannot post comments and thus posts answers instead to reach the OP of the question. In an effort to be nice and explain the rules I replied:

> I'm very sorry, but this is not how stackoverflow works. The answer section is reserved for answers only. Circumventing the reputation system like this will only get your post deleted. For the moment I have added your answer as a comment. Please refrain from posting comments as answers in the future! – jotasi 15 mins ago

So far so good. The thing that bothered me was his reply to my comment, namely:

> don't care mate

This to me sounds like: "I don't care about the rules.", which doesn't sit right with me. So what is the right way to react here. I don't feel that the comment is flag-worthy in itself.

Should I just walk away, counting on his answer getting deleted or is there anything else that I could/should do?

<sub>Note, I am not asking about how to react to the non-answer rather his latest comment.</sub>

Comment: Look like NAA to me. It's doesn't attempt to answer the question. It's a "Me too!" comment.

Comment: LQ queue? recommend deletion and continue with your day. Also you can downvote as it is not useful

Comment: .... And in about a week or two assume that same user to pop on meta, ranting about an answer ban and how rude we all are....

Comment: There is some protection against "I don't care" users, they'll get an automatic post ban when they don't care long enough.  A downvote on their post is the way to make that happen.

Comment: I've encountered [don't-care-dudes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293779/what-is-the-most-effective-way-of-encouraging-a-user-not-to-make-deliberate-writ) in the past, and I think the consensus is that they will get burned in the end. In other words, breaking the rules knowingly is not treated differently from doing so accidentally, unless they are doing it repeatedly.

Comment: (Meta: I have pinged that author on another of their posts, to let them know they are being discussed).

Comment: @gnat: My question was not about how to react to the non-answer but to the "I don't care about the rules"-comment. I've edited the question to emphasize that.

Comment: Comments shouldn't be punished on the post, but the user can be (by the mod). So you can flag the comment and do with the post as it needs (down, close, flag, etc).

Comment: @halfer he has 1 rep currently so he can't participate in meta, he can only watch.

Comment: Ah, thanks @RobertLongson, and apologies to that contributor - I don't think I was aware of that restriction. Still, I'd probably say it's good to let them know, for maximum transparency.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Ignore their reply.

Flagging the answer will lead to it getting deleted and, if they keep breaking the rules, they're going to get banned (automatically).

You can possibly also *flag their comment as rude*. Note that, as far as I know, that typically only leads to the comment getting deleted and doesn't have any negative consequences for the user (but it can lead to mod action in more extreme cases).

Comment: @AndréKool I doubt any mod will *disagree* with that comment being rude. It can also be flagged as "no longer needed", since it's most definitely unnecessary. Mods don't typically decline flags on comments that clearly aren't constructive, even if the reason isn't 100% correct.

Comment: yeah I agree with most comment flags being marked as helpful, I have raised ~200 comment flags and all have been helpful

Comment: _Specially if the user has rep >1_, I would suggest downvoting the answer as well _since it's a bad/not answer anyway_. That sends a direct message about the quality of the post and makes the user think twice. Usually, low rep users care about losing rep because it can also lead to losing privileges they had just earned.

Comment: Yep, this is 100% a special case of ["someone is wrong on the internet"](https://www.xkcd.com/386/).