# A new user has just rejected an edit of his answer written in poor English

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, rejected-edits, new-users

What to do as a new reviewer, when a new user rejects your edit of his contribution, even though it is clear it was written in poor English, and devoid of punctuation?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64210795/revisions) is the post in question.

Comment: In this case, the answer doesn't really contain any useful information aside from the link, so I'd flag it for deletion instead of editing

Comment: I'll just move along

Comment: @CertainPerformance: the post is already gone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters we've already met... but this time you're on my side, I feel the power

Comment: This is called "turd polishing", it's improving a post that can't be saved. Also, you haven't improved it by much, even if you were concerned with its language, you should've practically rewritten the entire post, and then still it'd not contain much useful.

Comment: As @CodeCaster says, the bigger issue is that you decided to edit an answer that is obviously destined for deletion. Doing so wastes everyone's time - please don't do it.

Comment: The minor edits are somewhat harmful to the community until you get [2000 points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Also refrain from editing posts solely to fix **only** spelling. Such edits are probably only worth to do to upvoted posts. Prioretise fixing tags, removing noise and improving formatting. Spelling is a nice bonus, but shouldn't be the only reason.

Comment: @Sinatr thank you for the tips, I will keep them in mind

Comment: The edit itself seems like a trivial edit and is only borderline better, if at all.

Comment: "The minor edits are somewhat harmful to the community until you get 2000 points." I don't understand this. Then why let people with <2000 points edit at all? And what makes someone's edit suddenly more useful when they reach that number? Surely novice editors are better making only small changes?

Comment: @RichardHunter that's not what was meant here, [beyond 2000 reputation, your edits are not reviewed by peers anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), menaing that trivial edit do not end up in a queue to be reviewed, wasting some more people (reviewers) time. Small change can do lots, though when they add code fence and such.

Comment: Unlike Wikipedia, posts on Stack Overflow are 'signed' with the poster's name. To me that means that the poster owns the post and has full say on what edits go into it and can accept or reject edits for whatever reason they want.

Comment: I think everyone has a different opinion of when proper grammar and punctuation is necessary.  I'd like to think "all the time", but not everyone agrees.  There's a balance between being grammatically correct vs discouraging someone from ever contributing again.  If your efforts aren't appreciated, then it might be better to just move on to something else and don't stress yourself over it.  Just IMHO...

Comment: @HansKilian [but that's not how SE works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In general, when users reject good edits that fix grammar and formatting issues, you can flag for moderator intervention. This can happen because new users haven't read the Help Center and don't realize that edits like this are common and normal. They usually just need someone to explain it to them.

For posts that have other problems requiring either edits that must come from the OP or deletion, flagging and voting appropriately is a better use of your time.

You may occasionally encounter a [user who insists on doing it wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293779/what-is-the-most-effective-way-of-encouraging-a-user-not-to-make-deliberate-writ), in which case the best thing to do is down vote and move on.

No matter what, avoid an edit war where you keep trying to apply the edit and they keep rolling it back.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I would do:

1. Create an edit that is *just* the English fixes. Have the edit description explicitly state that this is the purpose of the edit.
2. Apply that edit.
3. Make a comment explaining to the user why you edited - on the question page - and that it's important they let the edit stand.

If they still revert - it's a lost cause I guess.