# Silently prevent questions with the word "Support" 20+ times in the text from new accounts?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, spam

Questions like the one below are getting more and more common on SO. Yes, we get rid of them quickly with spam flags, but it seems like there's got to be a heuristic we can use to automatically prevent their being posted, such as not allowing a new account to post a question containing the word "support" 20+ times in the text (or to just silently fail to post it). Is that feasible?

This is probably just me being silly, I know we'd be at least a couple of orders of magnitude more spam than we do if the SE team weren't already on it, but I thought I'd flag up the pattern.

Here's the full text of a representative example we just burned on SO (the title gave the phone number, as if anyone would really be stupid enough to ring it):

> Outlook customer Support, Outlook customer Support, OutlookcustomerSupport, Outlook customer Support, Outlook customer Support,Outlookcustomer Support Outlook tech support,/Outlook Technical support, Canon PrinterAntivirusTechSupport, Outlook Customer Support, Outlookcontacsupport, OutlookcustomerSupport, Outlook contact supporthelpdesk,###############################################################
>
> Outlook customer Support, Outlook customerSupport,CanonPrinterhelpdesk , Outlook antivirus help desk, Outlooktoollfree,Outlook antivirushelp,Outlook antivirus support,CanonPrinter antivirus customer support, Outlook customer care, CanonPrinterantiviruscustomercare.################################################################################## Canon Printer tech support,/Outlook Technicalsupport,CanonPrinterAntivirusTech Support, Outlook Customer Support,

Comment: I have `Support` as one of my class names. I'm posting some code and a stack trace. Where'd my question go?

Comment: @Rizier123 I'd hellban them instead of deleting them. Let them think their posts are on the site. Deleting them would just encourage them to try to work around the spam blockers.

Comment: Intelligent blacklisting on these has been attempted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258317/the-body-of-my-post-cant-contain-82-213963 and didn't quite go as expected. The group behind this regularly varies the content they post: http://i.stack.imgur.com/namZJ.png and uses an enormous botnet to do so.

Comment: @TZHX: No filter is perfect, odds against a new user needing to do that seem vanishingly small.

Comment: @Rizier123 And yet their spam keeps getting through.

Comment: @BradLarson: Well, the *current* content reuses the words "support" and "tech" like mad. But again, you guys are in a much better position to know how to handle this.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: So weird to see your name without the diamond. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know. And I think in general you have a point that this spam is pervasive (though as Brad says it's also varying). I just wanted to point out that obvious solutions are probably going to have flaws (or, with trust in skills of SO devs, they'd have been implemented)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - From today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760412/1-855-709-2847canon-printer-tech-support-phone-numberusa1-855-709-2847 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737159/gmail-customer-service-1-888-361-3731-phone-number http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715478/1-844-780-6762aol-customer-support-phone-number-aol-customer-support-n http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715110/18447806762aol-technical-support-phone-number-aol-technical-support-nu . Note the variance in just those. Blocking "support" would cause them to move on to something else. They're persistent.

Comment: It's taken a month, but I'm finally getting used to not having it. :)

Comment: @BradLarson I hate those guys.

Comment: @BradLarson: See? I was being silly. Of course you guys are on it. :-)

Comment: To my knowledge, a [machine learning technique](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91177/machine-learning-techniques-for-spam-detection-and-in-general-for-text-classifi) can do such filtering. Of course, some basic information about the account posting the question might also be needed.

Comment: @TZHX That would be a [clbuttic mistake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)!

Comment: Just tell them to tag all their "questions" with the *spam* tag. Then we could safely ignore/hide/whatever them.

Comment: Using a CAPTCHA does look like a good solution. But I think SE team can make CAPTCHA more user friendly taking cues from the reCAPTCHA mobile-friendly (<http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html>). The user friendly CAPTCHAs will be a nice feature on SE compared to the twisted letter CAPTCHAs that we generally find elsewhere. I think the context based CAPTCHAs (asking users to find matching objects) would also turn out more secure.

Comment: **Similar**: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276105/add-this-is-my-first-post-and-several-other-phrases-to-the-question-content

Comment: Its hardly an issue at the current rate. They stand out like a sore thumb and so get downvoted to oblivion within seconds.

Comment: "*as if anyone would really be stupid enough to ring it*". Why do you think they keep doing it? There **are** people out there who are that stupid.

Comment: @ivarni: I was rounding off the extremely small fractional percentage just ever so slightly north of zero. And I was wondering whether this particular spamming was actually useful, or just part of a multi-pronged attack they haven't figured out isn't pulling its weight.

Comment: A large group of humans (i.e., the SO community) always makes for a better filter than any heuristic algorithm.

What we need is a way to mark a question as unsuitable, and given enough marks from validated users with enough reputation points, that message is no longer visible or shows up grayed out (visibly disabled).

Comment: See also [What is up with all the “printer support number” posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258401/262755) (and the accepted answer there)

Comment: @DavidRTribble Hmm, if only we had such a [magical tool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No joke, my mind inserted a diamond into his name the same way it [works out jumbled words](http://www.livescience.com/18392-reading-jumbled-words.html). "Hrm, SE must've misspelled Bill the Lizard again. That's easy to fix..." To the topic, [seems the spam nut has been at least partially cracked before](http://spamassassin.apache.org/). Not sure what would be that unique to SE/SO that leveraging/tweaking existing filters wouldn't work. At worst, show the "prove you're not a robot" page and/or run filtered question to a new type of review stack before posting.

Answer (score 27):

As a first step you could require users creating a new post (either question or answer) with less than `n` reputation to enter a captcha (or pass some other "Prove you're a human" test) before being permitted to submit the post (for some reasonably small value of `n` but not too small).

As a next step, perform a statistical analysis on the post to count word occurrences for users with less than `m` reputation (where `m` may or may not be equal to `n` above).  This can be compared to historic patterns of both spam and legitimate questions and answers.  If the submission falls too far outside the patterns normally associated with legitimate posts, then have the user respond to a captcha before permitting the post.

This should at least cut down on the spam making human handling a more manageable task.

Comment: Captcha's can be easier for a computer to solve then a human at times so that does not really work anymore.

Comment: @JoeW Then any tool that verifies that it's a human. I believe Google has a tool out that does a decent job, though I can't remember what it is.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html

Comment: The problem with google catpcha (which I believe SE does/did use for a time) is that there have been thread on here before now where people moan about how they cannot tell which image is what type, i.e. "select all cakes" or "select everything is that is a cat"

Comment: There is also the simple [Are You Human Challenge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278633/captcha-broken-on-stack-overflow-no-challenge-shown) and somehow I keep on failing that. [They may know something about me that I don't know myself](http://www.sheldonquotes.com/s1/103/if-you-were-a-robot/).

Comment: It'd be great if the bots used google image search to crack the "select all of type" challenges.

Comment: [What percent human do you need to pass a captcha?](http://thepunchlineismachismo.com/archives/comic/the-straw-that-broke-the-robocamels-exoskeleton)

Comment: @JoeW [This captcha might work](https://xkcd.com/810/)

Answer (score 1):

A maybe-obvious-maybe-not solution from someone with fresh eyes but no experience in security:

Encourage more people who are just looking at responses to become members.  And require a 1~2 day window between signing up and posting a question.  I was browsing heavily for months before I created an account, and only did so once I had a question I simply could not find.
And then, if someone posts spam like this, there's a special category for reporting it.  I'm not sure how the best method of banning would go.  Maybe ban their IP for a day and their account for a week for the first offense and ban their account forever for the second offense.  I don't know how bans and deleted accounts work here.  If a certain username gets completely deleted, can someone else claim it?  If not, banning these bots could be worse than letting them be, because all the usernames would be taken up very quickly...

But I also like the idea of silently blocking the spam.  It's possibly more complicated than it seems.  If there's a whole lot of accounts from one spambot, they could easily see that their spam is getting blocked.  Instead, let everyone with the spam flag on their account see all the spam, but no one without the spam flag can see it.  Usually that would be used for like an exclusive club, but in this case it's used in reverse.

Comment: There is a banner which encourages viewers to join up. The suggestion of a waiting period before posting has been discussed up and down and the general consensus has been that it would not affect bots (who don't care how long they have to wait) and it would turn away real users with real questions who don't have two days to wait to ask their question. There are already many methods (both systematic and organic) in place which take care of spam accounts/posts, and the vast majority of spam does not see the light of day. There are always false negatives, that is what this is about.