# Is there a pre-filter for questions posted by users with < ~10 rep?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, spam, quality-filter

After seeing another "obvious to a human" spam question posted on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31151849/6144

I have to wonder is this not something that can be caught before it even hits the "new questions" page?

E.g. If enough indicators get triggered the question should need approval before becoming visible.

- poster has very low or no rep
- question title contains no programming terms
- question body contains no code sample
- question body contains no programming terms
- (AND) question contains external links

Etc.

Just wondering if there can't be a preliminary filter that sniffs for fishy questions and "delays" their visibility on the new question page until a med-to-high rep user indicates it isn't spam.

Somewhat related, does StackOverflow actively ban user accounts, IP addresses or similar when the first "use" of an account is used for spam/hate/trolling...?

Comment: In all honesty, how often does something like this occur?  This is a **very** rare occurrence amongst the wave of spam that the site normally defends against, and the community is more than capable of handling it without it needing to go to through an automation process.

Comment: There are already three potential review queues that "question" would have made it to. It is very difficult to build something specifically for one site - you could pick some obvious indicators to put it on one of the existing queues, but how exactly do you definitively determine a post is purely spam? (and yes, there is already a ban mechanism based on IP).

Comment: Is there some way when flagging as spam, downvoting and applying a close vote to make the process faster? It pains me that this "lived" for almost 15 minutes before it was killed. I fear that letting this kind of thing live for more than 60 seconds sends the wrong message to spammers that SO is a place where they can sling their junk. At 10am EST M-F this kind of junk doesn't last for more than 2 min. But it seems that during off-peak North American work hours... It's a problem.

Comment: The trouble with filtering mechanisms like "Question title contains no programming terms" is that they're trivially easy for a spammer to work around (just add "Java" to the title). Even if the details of the algorithm are kept a secret, spammers are accustomed to checking to see if their message went through, and simple tricks are easy for them to find. (Incidentally, [there *is* a pre-filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards), though it focuses more on question quality than spam)

Answer (score 5):

There are some restrictions on new users that are intended to counter spam / trolling / question ban evasion. New users can be throttled or blocked from posting altogether based on previously identified spam, trolling, or terrible content that has come from their specific location. These kind of blocks or rate limits [keep out a lot of spam or troubling content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228043/would-anyone-care-for-some-processed-meat-like-substance-with-a-gelatinous-glaze).

There's a bit of intelligence in how this is done, as it's not entirely based on a single IP and is continually being adjusted. Almost all spammers are stopped in their tracks once even a single bit of attempted spam has been identified by the community. Some spammers [are more resourceful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296579/silently-prevent-questions-with-the-word-support-20-times-in-the-text-from-ne) and take a little more work to stop, but only the most persistent still keep trying in vain to get their spam on the site.

When a post is destroyed as spam / trolling, we usually destroy the account with it. That's as much of a "ban" as this site can provide, particularly coupled with the fact that they will be blocked from creating new accounts at their location (with "location" being a broader concept than just a single IP address).

No matter how good the anti-spam systems you put in place, a site this large will eventually have some being posted. That's where the community and the review system steps in. Pretty much all posts by new users are reviewed by the community in some manner, and spam tends to be identified and destroyed within minutes. Reviewers do occasionally screw up, but that only delays the inevitable for these spammers (it also identifies people who do not belong as reviewers).